# Multiple FIND criteria that are FILTERed

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I and using google sheets and am trying to combine these 3 `FILTER` `FIND` formulas with an `AND` so that I can `FILTER` data that matches all 3 criteria.
The formulas work independently but can give results that don't match up on the same line on the data table.

```
=FILTER(FILTER(Data!K2:K, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F)),
     IF(FILTER(Data!K2:K, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F))>=15, 
        FILTER(Data!K2:K, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F)), ""))

=FILTER(FILTER(Data!P2:P, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F)), 
     IF(FILTER(Data!P2:P, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F))<=""&F1&"", 
        FILTER(Data!P2:P, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F)), ""))

=FILTER(FILTER(Data!R2:R, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F)),
     IF(FILTER(Data!R2:R, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F))>=3,
        FILTER(Data!R2:R, FIND("Broad", Data!F2:F)), ""))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes that worked.
=FILTER(Data!$I$2:$I,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Broad",Data!$F$2:$F))*(Data!$K$2:$K>=15)*(Data!$P$2:$P<=$F$1)*(Data!$P$2:$P>0)*(Data!$R$2:$R>=$G$1))